# gapi.auth.authorize not working for Google Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0

Below is the code for my extension. I'm trying to authorize with Oauth2 to get access to the Google APIs, but I get the error message "TypeError: cannot read property 'authorize' of undefined" when the extension calls the gapi.auth.authorize() function. Any ideas as to what might be the problem?

Manifest:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "name",
"description": "description",
"version": "1.0",

    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com/js/client.js; object-src 'self'",
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
}
}
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="processform.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="myform">
         First name: <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" /><br />
         Last name:  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" /><br />
        <input name="Submit"  type="submit" value="Update" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
var CLIENT_ID = ' ... .apps.googleusercontent.com';
var SCOPES = [
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
];

function handleClientLoad() {
    checkAuth();
}

function checkAuth() {
    try {
        gapi.auth.authorize(
            {'client_id': CLIENT_ID, 'scope': SCOPES.join(' '), 'immediate': true},
            handleAuthResult);
    }
    catch(err) {
        var e = err.toString();
        alert(e);
    }
}


function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    if (authResult) {
    } else {
        gapi.auth.authorize(
            {'client_id': CLIENT_ID, 'scope': SCOPES.join(' '), 'immediate': false},
            handleAuthResult);
}
}

function ExampleJS(){
 }


 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  handleClientLoad();
});

 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.forms["myform"].addEventListener('submit', ExampleJS);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [chrome.identity](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity#method-getAuthToken) API? It might work better.

Comment: I read somewhere that I had to publish the extension to the Google web store if I used chrome.identity, and I don't really want to do that.

Comment: Comment above is not true but will make it harder if more than one user installs it. Look at the official samples there is a complete oauth one.

Comment: This is the official sample from https://developers.google.com/drive/web/credentials

Answer (score 1):

Your `content_security_policy` should be updated to `"script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com/; object-src 'self'"`. Loading the API triggers a callback that requires files outside of that single URL. You may even need to further widen the security policy depending on what other aspects of the waterfall below are needed for authorization.

[image: GAPI callbacks]

Comment: I still got the same error, then I updated the manifest to `"script-src 'self' https://; object-src 'self'"` for good measure and I still get the same error.

Comment: I don't believe you can simply whitelist all https origins. I updated the policy to `"script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com/ https://accounts.google.com https://oauth.googleusercontent.com https://ssl.gstatic.com; object-src 'self'"` based on the flow in the screenshot above but got the following error from OAuth: `Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?.....authuser=0' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.` May not be feasible to use the standard OAuth procedure here with popup.html living in a frame.